# Color image segmentation with Python

Tags: python-2.7, image-segmentation

I have many pictures as below:
[image: target picture example]

My objective is to identify those "beads", try to mark it with a circle, and count the detected numbers.

I tried to use image segmentation algorithms via Python and the source codes are as below:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import blob_dog, blob_log, blob_doh
from math import sqrt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from scipy import misc # try

image = misc.imread('test.jpg')
image_gray = rgb2gray(image)

blobs_log = blob_log(image_gray, max_sigma=10, num_sigma=5, threshold=.1)
# Compute radii in the 3rd column.
blobs_log[:, 2] = blobs_log[:, 2] * sqrt(2)

blobs_dog = blob_dog(image_gray, max_sigma=2, threshold=.051)
blobs_dog[:, 2] = blobs_dog[:, 2] * sqrt(2)

blobs_doh = blob_doh(image_gray, max_sigma=2, threshold=.01)

blobs_list = [blobs_log, blobs_dog, blobs_doh]
colors = ['yellow', 'lime', 'red']
titles = ['Laplacian of Gaussian', 'Difference of Gaussian',
          'Determinant of Hessian']
sequence = zip(blobs_list, colors, titles)

for blobs, color, title in sequence:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.imshow(image, interpolation='nearest')
    for blob in blobs:
        y, x, r = blob
        c = plt.Circle((x, y), r, color=color, linewidth=2, fill=False)
        ax.add_patch(c)

plt.show()
```

The best results obtained so far are still unsatisfactory:
[image: One of the results obtained]

How can I improve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Gimp or Photoshop and test some filters and colors changes to differentiate the circles from the background. Brightness and Contrast adjustments may work. Then you can apply an Edge detector to detect the circles.

Answer (score 1):

by converting this image to grayscale you have effectively thrown away the most powerful cue you have to segment the beads - their distinctive green color. try running the same code but replace

```
image_gray = rgb2gray(image)
```

with

```
image_gray = image[:,:,1]
```