# CV, detecting object size in photo (Python)

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am physicist, not a professional programmer. So I need the simplest, shortest possible solution to my problem. I have photo like this:

[image]

size  of each ball is 1cm, so i should detect them, calculate it's size in pixels and find scale. Then i will calculate distance between each two balls. We can't use manual marking, because of large number of photos. So I want to write python script that does it automatically. Сan you advice me on python libraries or frameworks that can solve my problem. Maybe there are some ready-made solutions for detection geometric figures on contrast background.

Comment: **OpenCV** is a good python image processing library that can do such tasks. 

Take a look at this article... https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/ 
or this github repo... https://github.com/Practical-CV/Measuring-Size-of-Objects-with-OpenCV ... You just need a reference point, meaning you have to tell OpenCV how many pixels a cm is. Calculating the distane between those balls is a bit more challenging.

Comment: The answers below are all good, just want to remind you, if you could make the balls have more contrast with the background (solid white or blue screen?), the program will do much better job.

Answer (score 3):

The Python package `opencv-python` is a great fit for this task.

Image segmentation based on color should work fine, you can couple it with edge detection as the balls are edges are well defined.

There are a lot of Stack Overflow questions about segmentation of things that could inspire you: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60159567/looking-for-different-methods-of-image-segmentation-for-pictures-of-apples), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52802910/opencv-color-segmentation-using-kmeans) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114250/color-image-segmentation-with-python).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simplistic method in Python/OpenCV.

```
 - Read the input image
 - Convert to HSV and save the Hue channel
 - Threshold at 165 since the beads are on the blue side of red and so have a high value out of 180. (OpenCV hues range from 0 to 180, which is half the normal 0 to 360 range).
 - Apply morphology open and close to remove excess white spots and fill holes.
 - Find external contours
 - Loop over each contour and get the minimum enclosing circles  radii and center
 - Draw the circles on a copy of the input
 - Compute the average radius
 - Save results and print average radius
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('beads.jpg')

# Convert to HSV and keep the hue channel
hue = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,0]

# beads are red but on the blue side, so very bright hues
# so threshold hue at 165 (out of 180)
thresh = cv2.threshold(hue, 165, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply morphology to fill beads and remove excess spots
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (6,6))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get contours and enclosing circles
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
circles = img.copy()
num_circles = len(contours)
ave = 0
for cntr in contours:
    center, radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cntr)
    cx = int(round(center[0]))
    cy = int(round(center[1]))
    rr = int(round(radius))
    # draw enclosing circle over beads
    cv2.circle(circles, (cx,cy), rr, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # cumulate radii for average
    ave = ave + radius

# print average radius
ave_radius = ave / num_circles
print("average radius:", ave_radius)
print ("number of circles:", num_circles)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('beads_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('beads_morph.jpg', morph)
cv2.imwrite('beads_circles.jpg', circles)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('circles', circles)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded Image:

[image]

Morphology Cleaned Image:

[image]

Circles on Input:

[image]

**Average Radius and Count:**

```
average radius: 13.95605175635394
number of circles: 34
```